# Special entangled tripartite state

Tags: entanglement

Suppose three particles a, b and c

a is entangled with b,

a is entangled with c,

b and c are separatable

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, here's a simple example. Suppose $A$ is a $d$ dimensional system with $d \geq 4$ and $d$ not prime. Then I can find a bipartition of $A$ into two subpaces $A_1, A_2$ of dimension at least $2$ such that $A=A_1\otimes A_2$ then
$$
\rho_{CAB} = \rho_{CA_1} \otimes \rho_{A_2B}
$$
satisfies your conditions whenever you take $\rho_{CA_1}$ and $\rho_{A_2B}$ to be entangled states.

Comment: Seems your example is not a tripartite state ( three particle)

Comment: Yes it is, I'm just reinterpreting $A$ as a bipartite system. For example, if $A$ is a 4 dimensional system it is possible to reinterpret the Hilbert space as representing two qubits (even if it physically is a single particle).

Comment: Then its not the case i asked. I guess its impossible for 3 particles.

Comment: @reza if you want 3 qubits, there is some constraints from monogamy (at least if the system is symmetric under exchanging B and C), e.g. the state cannot be one-way distillable. Not sure if this ruled out such a state, though. The right keyword is "symmetrically extendible".

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3530

Comment: Indeed, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.187904 seems to imply that this is impossible for qubits. (The extension would be a 2x4 system where PPT is equivalent to separability.) Haven't fully thought this through, though.

Comment: Your question says nothing about the dimensions of the systems involved. If you want more specifically three qubits then you should specify this in the question.

Comment: @Rammus saying three particle is enough.  It shows dimensions of the hilbert space automatically.

Comment: @reza No it does not in general. A ``particle'' implies a Hilbert space but *not* the dimension. So when you say 3 particles you specify a tripartite Hilbert space but *not* that each Hilbert space is 2 dimensional.

Comment: Can u give a example where we have three particles in higher dimension? Or something like that

Comment: The position/momentum of a single particle requires an infinite dimensional Hilbert space to describe. I'll let someone else give a better example because my physics is quite weak.